# How to write typical C# one-liners as separate pieces of code?

Tags: c#, prism

I'm taking over a Prism-based C# application that contains quite some lambda-ish one-liners, like the following:

```
using Prism.Interactivity.InteractionRequest;
...
public InteractionRequest<Confirmation> OwnObjectRequest { get; } = new InteractionRequest<Confirmation>();
...
OwnObjectRequest.Raise(confirmation, c => // one-liner
{
    Confirmation conf = (Confirmation)c;
    if (conf.Confirmed)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
});
```

I would like to program in a cleaner way, by which I mean that I only want to put one single action on one single line, but I don't get it done (what's the signature of `some_Method`, how to use it in order to define an action, ...?)
This is what I have until now:

```
public ... some_Method(...)
{
    Confirmation conf = (Confirmation)c;
    if (conf.Confirmed)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}

Action actionToPerform = new Action(some_Method);
OwnObjectRequest.Raise(confirmation, actionToPerform);
```

Does anybody know how to write this?

I don't think there's any technical advantage in writing such a one-liner in multiline format, but it would heavily help me understand how to read, understand and maybe give support for this source code.

Comment: I think you should elaborate a bit more on the intent, do you want to remove the use of lambdas altogether due to a personal choice/preference or are you looking for a setup that make it easier to debug through it: that clarification can lead to very different responses.

Comment: Do you mean one-liner for this:`if(c is Confirmation conf && conf.Confirmed) DoSomething()`? I am not sure what you call "one-liner" in your first example, I count 8 lines ;)

Comment: @Sinatr: I don't want oneliners, I want to avoid them. The answer of Freeman is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly or not, but you can define a separate method or use a lambda expression directly

so for example if you want separate mtehod :

```
public void HandleConfirmation(Confirmation confirmation)
{
    if (confirmation.Confirmed)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

and then, you can use this method as the action to be raised:

```
OwnObjectRequest.Raise(confirmation, HandleConfirmation);
```

or using a lambda expression

```
OwnObjectRequest.Raise(confirmation, c =>
{
    Confirmation conf = (Confirmation)c;
    if (conf.Confirmed)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. My biggest problem was the `Action` object: I was convinced that such a thing was needed in the `.Raise(...)` method, I never realised that I could just write the method name there.